# Linking Static HTML page in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm new to using vue and I would like to link a static html page from the public folder from an a tag. The tag I have now is
`<a href="../../public/HU/vii/index.html">`
But when clicking on the link when running, I get the message "Cannot GET /public/HU/vii/index.html". I'm unsure on what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a Vue CLI scaffolded project, the `public` folder is served as the static root, so you don't need to reference the `public` path directly.

In this case, the `href` should point to the path relative to `public`:

```html
<a href="HU/vii/index.html">Link</a>

<!-- or simply -->
<a href="HU/vii">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! The href path worked. Also figured that the static folder was actually the static root of my project instead of the public folder.